# Show mysql tables into qlik view?

Tags: mysql, qlikview

I am using QlikView version 11 with the MySQL database.

I have created a database and one table in MySQL. Now i want to load that table in QlikView. I have created a data source, but my database is not showing in QlikView.

Comment: Is this issue already solved? If not: which type of DSN did you use, System-DSN? Are the credentials OK? Do you see any other datasource from QlikView?

Comment: have you connected to the data source ?? after going into the edit script and check whether you are connected with your database ??

Comment: What kind of connection are you using? OleDB or ODBC?

Comment: What version of QV11 are you using - 32 or 64 bit?  Make sure you create the DSN in the correct version of the ODBC Administrator (i.e. 32 or 64 bit version).  You can access the 32 bit version in c:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe, and the 64 bit version in C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe.  Horribly confusing paths - but don't shoot the messenger!

Answer (score 1):

In qlikview create a new file (CTRL+N). If the wizard comes up, click cancel.

Now edit the load script (CTRL-E).

At the bottom in data tab select database as ODBC and click on Connect and then check **show user DSN if you have created a data source under user DSN** enter credentials and then click on test connection and then press ok.
Then press (Ctrl+E) and press select button at the bottom then all the tables present in your database will be listed, select the table and the columns you want to load in to qlikview.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your database is up and you can connect it via [odbc](/questions/tagged/odbc).

(I use the german UI of qlikview so maybe my translation 
of the menu entries do not fit exactly.)

In clikview create a new file (CTRL+N).
If the wizzard comes up, click cancel.

Now edit the load script (CTRL-E).

At the bottom you can selct were your data comes from.
Take ODBC from the Database select and then click connect.

Select your datasource and enter the credentials.
After that you should test your connection!
After a successfull test you can klick OK.

Now you should have a ODBC Line in your script, like this

```
ODBC CONNECT TO [Foo;DBQ=bar] (XUserId is UAIAARGJCEEEF, XPassword is DFASDYFSFGbbCWERAB);
```

Now click the select button in the database section at the bottom. A window
pops up and you can select the columns and tables you need.
Try the proposal first ans click OK.

Now you should have your fist LOAD command from your database.

```
LOAD `run_id`,
   `question_id`,
   question; 
SQL SELECT *
FROM foobar.run;
```

Click OK to finish the editing of the script.

Press CTRL+R to reload the data. (Save your *.qvw file if not already done.)

Now click right in your sheet and add a listbox for a coloumn. e.g. 'question' in this example.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
You will first need to install an ODBC connector.
Follow this [Download link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)
**Step 2**
Add user DSN, enter appropriate entries.
After that follow this video: [Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STsYZHUoFrM)

Hope this will solve your problem.